# how to configure java on windows 10

Tags: java, windows

I suddenly found that I could no longer run my own developed JAVA apps by simply double-clicking the JAR file - it reported that the main class was not found.

With trial and error I found that if I forced 32-bit JAVA 1.8.0_161 to run then things worked fine. What was running by default was 64-bit JAVA 1.9. I also found it was not using JAVA_HOME but instead was running what it found in %APPDATA%\Oracle\Java.

I tried lots of things but in the end I uninstalled the 64-bit JAVA 1.9, put the path for 1.8.0_161 in JAVA_HOME, put %JAVA_HOME%\bin in the PATH and that got me most of the way...

Now if I run **java -jar <jarFileName.jar>** then my program runs just fine, but if I attempt to run the jar file by double clicking on it then it still could not load the main class.

Windows 10 default programs for JAR files says **Java(TM) Platform SE Binary** - tried forcibly changing this to point to the java.exe for 1.8.0_161 but that still doesn't work.

The JAVA Settings Console doesn't look like the ones in various web queries - I think it changed with 64-bit JAVA.

So I suspect my system is no longer properly configured.

How do I fixup the configuration to get back to where I can simply double click a JAR file in order to run it.

Best Regards
SteveM

Comment: Perhaps a script is overriding your `JAVA_HOME`.  But, I don't know what that might be.

Comment: Maybe use Posh-GVM?  http://www.westerndevs.com/java/posh-gvm/